# Imagemagick fill with opaque color Gray issue

Tags: windows, imagemagick, fill

I need create 50% RGB Gray canvas from existing image to my task.

And using this command to do this:

```
magick.exe 00_B.tif -fill fractal -opaque fractal 000.png
```

or

```
magick.exe 00_B.tif -alpha Opaque +level-colors "rgb(50%,50%,50%)" 000.tif
```

Original image is 16bit RGB
But Imagemagick always save png or tif or jpg as Grayscale image.

When i define non Gray color

```
magick.exe 00_B.tif -fill fractal -opaque Sienna 000.tif
```

ImageMagick save RGB image with Sienna color on it.

What i missed and how should i create 50% Grayscale image?

I plan to use it with `-write MPR:GrayLayer` in final command so not actual write as a RGB file is needed.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are actually trying to do... your question kind of says *"I want to make a 50% grey something but it always comes out grey"* - which sounds correct to me.

Comment: And why are you trying to use `-fill fractal` and `-alpha opaque` to make something grey?

Comment: I need RGB #808080 or 50%,50%,50%

Comment: `convert -size 640x480 xc:'#808080' a.png`

Comment: Mark, sorry, but existing file size, that can have “unknown” size.

Comment: What do you mean? All images have a size! Please click `edit` under your question and update it to be a lot clearer about what you are trying to do - else everybody wastes their time guessing. Thank you.

Comment: Mark, sorry. My question is clear. Script should run with any size image input. So I can’t define canvas size in command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ImageMagick, you can create a 50% Gray image and save as RGB as follows:

For TIF output:

```
convert 00_B.tif -fill "gray(50%)" -colorize 100 -type truecolor result.tif
```

For PNG output:

```
convert 00_B.tif -fill "gray(50%)" -colorize 100 PNG24:result.png
```

Alternately:

```
convert 00_B.tif -evaluate set 50% -type truecolor result.tif

convert 00_B.tif -evaluate set 50% PNG24:result.png
```

Comment: What the fastest way? Why I just can’t fill with #808080 RGB color?

Comment: You can also do `convert 00_B.tif -evaluate set 50% PNG24:result.png`